# Parameterization which is closed under addition

Tags: real-analysis, problem-solving, parametric

Suppose $\beta_1(t)$ and $\beta_2(t)$ are two parametric curves defined on $[0,1]$. Let $\beta_1^*(t)$ and $\beta_2^*(t)$ are two re-parametrized of the above curves.

Now, I looking for a re-parametrization, where the sum of two re-parametrized curve also have the same properties as the component curves (reparametrized curve).

To clarify the above question: let us consider the arc-length parametrization (unit speed) of $\beta_1(t)$ and $\beta_2(t)$ as $\beta_1^*(t)$ and $\beta_2^*(t)$, respectively, than  the sum function $\beta_1^*(t)+\beta_2^*(t)$ is **not** arc-length parametrized (not having unit speed). So arc length parametrization is not that I am looking for.

Any suggestions! Thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are looking for. What does "similarly re-parameterized" mean for you? (If this is part of a bigger problem, it could be a good idea to say something about it).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro. By similarly parametrized I meant the  sum have the same property as the component functions. Like in arc-length parametrization, the component functions has unit speed but the sum function does not have unit speed.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I clarified the above point in the main question. Thank you very much